# Getting possible runtime error in java at URI on line judge

Tags: java, string, exception, runtime-error

I am trying to solve a problem at URI on line judge but getting possible runtime error. I tried hard to figure out the error but cant understand where my code generates an exception. I know that its due to the code where I'm taking  the input and not in the part where I am finding lcs.

It would be very helpful if anyone could tell me where I am having the error or any such test case where this error is proved. [Here is the link to the problem](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/problems/view/1341)

```
package URI;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class KidsGrid {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        String s;
        StringTokenizer st;
        int T;          
        int caser=1;
        T=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        while(T>0)
        {
            String first="",second="";
            char fir[],sec[];
            fir=sec=null;
            if((s=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                s=s.trim();                     
                st=new StringTokenizer(s);                  
                int H=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                int W=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                char arr[][]=new char[H+1][W+1];
                for(int i=1;i<=H;)
                {
                    if((s=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        for(int j=1;j<=W;j++)
                        {
                            arr[i][j]=s.charAt(j-1);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                if((s=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    s=s.trim();
                    st=new StringTokenizer(s);          
                    int N=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int x=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int y=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    first+=arr[x][y];
                    if(N>0&&(s=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        s=s.trim();                             
                        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
                        {

                            switch(s.charAt(i-1))
                            {
                                case 'N':
                                x--;
                                break;
                                case 'S':
                                x++;
                                break;
                                case 'W':
                                y--;
                                break;
                                case 'E':
                                y++;
                                break;
                            }
                            first+=arr[x][y];

                        }
                        first=first.trim();
                        fir=first.toCharArray();
                    }
                }


                if((s=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    s=s.trim();
                    st=new StringTokenizer(s);          
                    int N=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int x=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int y=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    second+=arr[x][y];
                    if((s=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        s=s.trim();
                        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
                        {

                            switch(s.charAt(i-1))
                            {
                                case 'N':
                                x--;
                                break;
                                case 'S':
                                x++;
                                break;
                                case 'W':
                                y--;
                                break;
                                case 'E':
                                y++;
                                break;
                            }
                            second+=arr[x][y];

                        }
                        second=second.trim();
                        sec=second.toCharArray();

                    }
                }                                           

                if(sec!=null && fir!=null)
                {
                    int lcs[][]=new int[fir.length+1][sec.length+1];
                    for(int i=0;i<=fir.length;i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0;j<=sec.length;j++)
                        {
                            if(i==0||j==0)
                                lcs[i][j]=0;
                            else if(fir[i-1]==sec[j-1])
                                lcs[i][j]=lcs[i][j-1]+1;
                            else
                                lcs[i][j]=Math.max(lcs[i][j-1],lcs[i-1][j]);

                        }

                    }
                        //System.out.println("Common"+ lcs[fir.length][sec.length]);
                    int a=fir.length-lcs[fir.length][sec.length];
                    int b=sec.length-lcs[fir.length][sec.length];
                    System.out.println("Case "+caser+": "+a+" "+b);
                    caser++;
                    T--;
                }
                        //System.out.println("T="+T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of your exception, please?

Comment: It is the part of  generating the longest common subsequence.But its does not cause any error because i tried submitting commenting the last two for loops.in the last iteration it will compare fir[i-1](last character of first string) with all the characters of second string

Comment: I dnt have the stack trace because i dnt understand where my code is failing.but when i submit this code i am getting possible runtime error at URI online judge

Comment: @aa1992 can you provide the stacktrace.Put your code in try catch and print the stacktrace

Comment: @singhakash i understand what you are saying.I tried printing stack trace but i am not getting exception in my code when i am giving the inputs.But i am getting possible runtime error when i am submitting the code to URI.So how do i provide you the stack trace when i am not getting any exception.My code is running perfect when i am providing the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.I was getting the possible runtime error due to extra blank spaces in the input file at URI online judge.
Instead of using br.readLine(), br.readLine().trim() solved my problem.